# SQL Server result on textbox vb window form application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, textbox, max

I have a `SELECT` statement for `ListView` and for `ListBox` even for `DataGrid` the only problem is that I can't display a result to my `TextBox` I just want to use:

> The MAX() Function

I want to used `MAX()` because it says that it will return the larges value of the selected column, since I used `INCREMENT` to my ID `MAX()` Function is my one way to do it.

I used this codes to generate the ID:

```
 Dim p1num As Integer = 0
        p1num += 1
txtPNumber.Text = p1num.ToString("D4")
```

Comment: Where is your code?........ where your getting problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to understand your question and I think you should used this:

Try:

```
            Dim querystring As String = "SELECT MAX(pIDNo) FROM (Name of your Table)"
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=(Name of your DB);Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(Your User);Password=(Your Pass)")
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(querystring, connection)
                connection.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                Dim value = String.Empty
                While reader.Read
                    value = reader.GetString(0)
                End While
                txtPNumber.Text = Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) & Today.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & (Integer.Parse(value.Substring(4, value.Length - 4)) + 1).ToString("D4")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtPNumber.Text = Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) & Today.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & num.ToString("D4")
        End Try
```

Try to make a Private Sub with it and used it to the Form Load if you want to display it after the program run or on button if you want a trigger to display the ID that you want.